# calculator in C - input a whole formula

Tags: c, calculator

I'm trying to code a calculator in C, and want to make one that can calculate a multiple inputs, eg, (5*9 + 1 -2). These inputs can be completely random and I'm stuck on how to do this.

I know how to initialize a variable, and ask the user input a number and all that, but if the user wanted to add up 50 random numbers, that calculator wouldn't be able to do that.

Hope you can help, or share some tips

Thanks !

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: You need to implement some algorithms in order to do it properly, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15173980/1113392) for some hints on where to start

Comment: To calculate an arbitrary expression you will need some data structures like stack or expression tree to store expression nodes and than traverse them and calculate. You should try first calculating expressions without parentheses , then you'll need to split string using spaces and math operation symbols (+ - * /) as delimitors. Then depending on the  current operation you'll just add current value to the sum or modify it with multiplier/divisor.

Comment: @L.Butz I have no idea where to start. I thought of saving the input into a string, then using a for loop to go through that string and take out each value and arithmetic symbol and I'm not sure where to go after that

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement an expression parser that will take operator precedence into account. To me the two simplest ways to do this would be to either implement a recursive decent parser or to implement the [Shunting yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

See [this](http://www.ubasics.com/simple_c_equation_parser) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you need to read the entire line (it shouldn't be too hard),
then you need to parse it and store it into some data structures.

Here are two ways I know to store and use it :

- The first one : it's easy to do, easy to use, **but not beautiful nor fast** :
  A double linked-list with each link containing an operator **or** a number and a priority if it's an operator (you can use an enum + union if you want something cleaner):

  ```
  struct list {
      struct list *prev;
      struct list *next;
      char operator;
      int number;
      unsigned int priority;
  }
  ```

  You loop trough your string and apply an easy algorithm for priority (pseudocode):

  ```
  var priority = 0
  var array = cut string // ["5", "+", "3", "*", "(", "6", "-", "2", ")"]

  check string // verify the string is correct

  for each element of array :
      if (element is number)
          store in list

      else if (element is operator)
          store in list
          if (element is '*' or '/' or '%')
              set his priority to priority + 1
          else
              set his priority to priority

      else if (element is open parenthesis)
          priority += 2

      else if (element is close parenthesis)
          priority -= 2
  ```

  For example :

  string:

  ```
  5 + 3 * (6 - 2) - 1
  ```

  priorities:

  ```
    0   1    2    0
  ```

  Then, to do your calculations :

  ```
  while list isn't empty:
      find operator with the highest priority // if there is more than one, take the first
      calculate this operator // with the element prev and next
      replace by result in list // operator, but also prev and next
  ```

  An example, again, with `5 + 3 * (6 - 2) - 1` :

  first iteration:

  ```
  5 + 3 * 4 - 1
  ```

  then

  ```
  5 + 12 - 1
  ```

  then

  ```
  17 - 1
  ```

  then

  ```
  16
  ```
- The other (and better, even though it is a little bit harder if you're not familiar with recursion) one : A binary tree using the [reverse polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation)
  (see [here](http://www.teach-ict.com/as_as_computing/ocr/H447/F453/3_3_7/revpolish/miniweb/pg5.htm) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895308/converting-from-reverse-polish-notationrpn-into-a-tree-form))

  This one is more common, so I won't explain it.

Comment: 1 more question, how can I cut the string, for the line 'var array = cut string ' . Also,  I didn't understand what u meant by 'check string' to see if it was correct, is there a function to do this, or was the else if parts checking it already?

Comment: @Cray In order to cut the string, you'll have to do a little bit of parsing, but you can start by cutting it with spaces (`3 + 4` become `["3", "+", "4"]`) by using [strtok](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok). (If you do so, every character will have to be separated by a space...)


The "check string" checks syntax errors like unmatched parenthesis or two operators (or numbers) in a row (`3 + * 4` isn't a valid operation, neither is `3 4 + 5`), unknown characters (`3 + 4NINJA` isn't valid either), and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string when you read and divide that string when you find `{+,-,*,/}.` And what you find between them are your numbers.

Try to add your code!

Good luck!

Comment: I thought of saving the input into a string, then using a for loop to go through that string and take out each value and arithmetic symbol and I'm not sure where to go after that. Is this the most efficient way to go?

Comment: Simple..first you have to slect the first value and save into X let's say(before first arithmetic symbol) and then at each symbol you find take the value after it and do what that symbol is meant to with the X .

Answer (score 0):

It's not a complete solution but hey it's something...
try this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SIZE (1000)

static char tempNumStr[50] = {0};
static double parsedDoubleArr[5] = {0};
static char parsedOperators[5] = {0};

void flushTempArr(char tmpArr[50]){
    for(int i=0; i< 50; i++)
        tmpArr[i]  = 0 ;
}

int tempNumStrIterator=0;

int parsedDoubleArrIterator=0;
int parsedOperatorsIterator=0;


int main(void)
{


    char operator;
    char sourceStr[] = "(17.5 + 8)";

    for(int i = 0; sourceStr[i] != '\0'; ++i) /*iterate over string till \0 */
    {
        if (IsDigit(sourceStr[i]))
        {
            while(sourceStr[i] != '\0' && IsDigit(sourceStr[i]))
            {
                tempNumStr[tempNumStrIterator++] = sourceStr[i];
                ++i;
            }

            sscanf(tempNumStr, "%lf", &parsedDoubleArr[parsedDoubleArrIterator++]);
            flushTempArr(tempNumStr);
            tempNumStrIterator = 0;
        }

        if (IsCalcOperator(sourceStr[i]))
        {
            parsedOperators[parsedOperatorsIterator++] = sourceStr[i];
        }

        else if (IsBracket(sourceStr[i]))
        {
            //do something
            continue;
        }
    }

    //do what you want with parsedDoubleArr and parsedOperators

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```